# AddServiceEndpoint throws key is null?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, endpoint

When using the ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint to add the custom ProtoEndpointBehavior I get the following exception :

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   key    at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key) 
>   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.ContainsKey(TKey key)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.ImplementedContractsContractResolver.ResolveContract(String
>   contractName)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.ServiceAndBehaviorsContractResolver.ResolveContract(String
>   contractName)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LookupContractForStandardEndpoint(String
>   contractName, String serviceName)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LookupContract(String
>   contractName, String serviceName)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceEndpoint
>   endpoint)    at
>   My.Service.Business.ServiceHandler.StartService(Type serviceType,
>   String uri, SecureConnectionSettings secureConnectionSettings) in
>   C:\My\Produkter\My
>   Utveckling\Solution\My.Service.Business\ServiceHandler.cs:line 150

This is how the code looks like :

```
ServiceHost serviceHost = null;
Console.WriteLine("Creating service " + serviceType.FullName);
serviceHost = new MyServiceHost(serviceType, new Uri(uri));

var endPointAddress = "";

HttpBindingBase binding = null;
if (secureConnectionSettings != null && secureConnectionSettings.Enabled)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Setting certificates");
    X509Store store = new X509Store(secureConnectionSettings.CertificateStore, secureConnectionSettings.CertificateLocation);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    X509Certificate2Collection certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, secureConnectionSettings.Thumbprint, true);
    store.Close();

    if (certs.Count > 0)
        serviceHost.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(secureConnectionSettings.CertificateLocation,
                                                                secureConnectionSettings.CertificateStore,
                                                                X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                                                                secureConnectionSettings.Thumbprint);
    else
        throw new Exception("Could not finde certificate with thumbprint " + secureConnectionSettings.Thumbprint);

    endPointAddress = uri + "/BinaryHttpsProto";
    binding = CreateNetHttpsBinding(secureConnectionSettings);
}
else
{
    endPointAddress = uri + "/BinaryHttpProto";
    binding = CreateNetHttpBinding();
}

var endpoint = new System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint(new System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescription(typeof(IMyClientService).FullName), 
    binding, 
    new EndpointAddress(endPointAddress));

endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new ProtoBuf.ServiceModel.ProtoEndpointBehavior());
serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(endpoint);

Console.WriteLine("Starting service...");
serviceHost.Open();
Console.WriteLine("Service started successfully (" + uri + ")");
return serviceHost;
```

I use to set this in config file like this :

```
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="protoEndpointBehavior">
      <protobuf />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
```

Now I need to add it in code instead.

What is wrong?

Comment: Which line in the code that you've posted is throwing that error?

Comment: @FeryalBadili It is thrown on the endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add row.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a [known bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/777134/servicehost-addserviceendpoint-serviceendpoint-method-throws-argumentnullexception) and there is workaround for it.

When obtaining instance of ContractDescription, use static method [ContractDescription.GetContract(Type)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576727(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of direct ContractDescription() constructor:

```
var endpoint = new System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint(System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IMyClientService)), 
    binding, 
    new EndpointAddress(endPointAddress));
```

I was able to reproduce your problem and this workaround worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are seeing the exception is because `ServiceEndpoint` assumed you use configuration file. It is trying to retrieve & resolve your contract, binding and address that doesn't exist because you are not using config file.

[ServiceEndpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms586146(v=vs.110).aspx) (see remarks)

> Use this constructor when the binding and address for the endpoint are
>   provided in configuration.

There are number of ways to [create or retrieve a ContractDescription](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.contractdescription(v=vs.110).aspx) object:

```
var contractUsingName = new ContractDescription("IProtoBufService");
var contractUsingNameWithNameSpace = new ContractDescription("IProtoBufService", "http://www.tempuri.org");
var contractUsingContractType = ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IProtoBufService));
var contractUsingContractTypeAndObjectImp = ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IProtoBufService), ProtoBufService);
var contractUsingContractTypeAndObjectType = ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IProtoBufService), typeof(ProtoBufService));
```

If you really insist to create `ContractDescription` programmatically you need to define some of the following:

- ContractDescription
- OperationDescription
- MessageDescription
- OperationBehaviorAttribute
- And other stuff...

Or you can follow this [blog](http://www.ingebrigtsen.info/2008/02/01/programatically-creating-a-wcf-contract-and-exposing-it-part1/) as a kicker.

Have you tried CodeFuller's answer? His answer could make your life easier. I made a quick check and it work.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/ProtoBuf");

        using (var serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ProtoBufService), baseAddress))
        {
            var endpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IProtoBufService)),
                new NetHttpBinding(),
                new EndpointAddress(baseAddress));

            endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new ProtoEndpointBehavior());
            serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(endpoint);

            serviceHost.Open();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I could not attached an image *"something's wrong with imgur"* but it work on my web browser. Though I haven't tested using client app but I guess you are already near to the solution.

**Tip :** Don't mix configuration file and code because it is very difficult to maintain. *"Which you probably knew"* Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks! Yes CodeFuller seems to solve the problem but im still checking if its really solved.